# android replace unlock screen

Tags: android, replace, screen, unlock

I am searching for a way to implement a custom unlocking screen for Android. There seem to be lots of questions about that but no real way to do that, am I right?

Solutions I found are about creating an activity that is invoked by some mechanism, that have to disable or bypass the home key and other keys and so on.

The simplest way in my imagination should be giving android an activity and say hey if you lock the screen and the user wants to wake it up, call this and wait for it to respond if unlocking is ok or not.
Handling stays within the system, that activity does not have to receive any key events, the system does not respond to home key in this situation...

Is there a chance?